# Why do I see discrepancy in tag counts on web client vs mobile client?

Tags: bug, tags

I recently noticed i see different numbers in tags using web client and mobile client.
For example i see `50 bash x 42` and  `13 python x 29` on web client and `53 bash x 42` and `20 python 29` on mobile client.

Could anyone explain which one is correct and why it happens?

Example of my web client:

[image: From the web client.]

And mobile client:

[image: From the mobile client.]

Comment: i added images, so it's hope it's more clear right now

Comment: [It might have to do with caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)